Get system icon for folders in Electron
I am trying to display some contents of a folder in my Electron app, and am fetching the system icons of each file and subfolder with app.getFileIcon(filePath). However, icons for folders are not found (it returns [Error: Failed to get file icon.]. I haven't been able to find anything online about how to get these icons.
If anyone knows how I can get the system icons for folders it would be greatly appreciated. I am using Ubuntu.
Thanks!
